# Android: return null when creating object from json using Gson

Tags: android, json, parsing, gson, datamodel

this is the json i'm trying to parse into Object :

```
{
  "api_token": "93244c644f3bb8d35b933fafef9556a5",
  "data": [
    {
      "_id": "5685cd7cda50430406e428a6",
      "created_at": "2016-01-01T00:51:08.438Z",
      "updated_at": "2016-01-01T00:51:08.438Z",
      "description": "bbdbbcbcbndb",
      "title": "ndjfjccjjcjnd",
      "__v": 0,
      "student_accepted": false,
      "quiz_type": 0,
      "quiz_chat_id": [],
      "quiz_time": 0,
      "quiz_status": false,
      "ask_by": "5685c8cada50430406e428a5",
      "answer_by": null
    }
  ]
}
```

and these are the classes i've trying to parse to :

```
public class RecentModel {

    private String api_token;
    private List<QuestionModel> data;
}
public class QuestionModel {

  private String _id;
  private String created_at;
  private String updated_at;
  private String description;
  private String title;
  private int __v;
  private boolean student_accepted;
  private int quiz_type;
  private List<Integer> quiz_chat_id;
  private int quiz_time;
  private boolean quiz_status;
  private String ask_by;
  private String answer_by;

  private String image;
  private String path;
  private ArrayList<ChatModel> quiz_chat;
}
```

but `gson.fromJson(response, RecentModel.class);` returns null.
i've done it before but this time i really don't know where is my problem!?
glad if someone helps.

Comment: Do you have getters and setters for each of those fields?

Comment: yep but didn't paste them here...

Comment: try "gson.fromJson(response.toString(), RecentModel.class);"

Comment: A constructor for your objects? Gson annotations so the fieldnames are mapped on the getters/setters? I also don't see any `image` or `path` values in your JSON.

Comment: No need for "private ArrayList<ChatModel> quiz_chat;"

Comment: last three items are used in client side and i dont think thats the problem, but however i tested without them, no luck.

Comment: Remove "private String answer_by;" and try.... Don't use it either... Post response.

Comment: no luck yet. still returns null!

Comment: have you instanciate gson ? I mean have you wrote "Gson gson = new Gson();" ?

Comment: Rename class "QuestionModel" to "Data".

Comment: not working ! :( ...

Comment: Haha.... what are you writing to get your "Log ?" What is exactly returning Null ?

Comment: i do call getApiToken() on the object that created by gson...
it will cause nullpointerexception because i invoke a method on a null object.

Comment: "Gson g = new Gson();
        RecentModel r = g.fromJson(jObj,RecentModel.class);
        List<QuestionModel> q = r.getData();
        Log.e(TAG,"::::::"+r.getApi_token());
        Log.e(TAG,"::::::"+q.get(0).get_id());"       try this....

Comment: Thank you Tushar Sheth.....
the problem was in the response i was getting...
some how for some strange reasons my previous method did log the response correctly but didn't send it as an valid arg to my second method!
it was solved by re positioning the call to my parsing method.

Comment: Could you upvote ? Did you got your answer ?